# NHibernate session getting closed though registered type using Unity per request

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, nhibernate, unity-container

I am using FluentNHibernate and Unity to use in my asp.net webapi. I am using Unit of work pattern to configure the ISession.

I am getting error as `"Session is closed! Object name: 'ISession'.` Can anyone help what am i doing wrong here? Please find below my code.

unityconfig:

```
container.RegisterType<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());

public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    private static readonly ISessionFactory _sessionFactory;
    private ITransaction _transaction;

    public ISession Session { get; set; }

    static UnitOfWork() 
    {
        _sessionFactory = Fluently.Configure()
            .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008.ConnectionString(x => x.FromConnectionStringWithKey("UnitOfWorkExample")))
            .Mappings(x => x.AutoMappings.Add(
                AutoMap.AssemblyOf<Product>(new AutomappingConfiguration()).UseOverridesFromAssemblyOf<ProductOverrides>()))
            .ExposeConfiguration(config => new SchemaUpdate(config).Execute(false, true))
            .BuildSessionFactory();
    }

    public UnitOfWork()
    {
        Session = _sessionFactory.OpenSession();
    }

    public void BeginTransaction()
    {
        _transaction = Session.BeginTransaction();
    }

    public void Commit()
    {
        try
        {
            if (_transaction != null && _transaction.IsActive)
                _transaction.Commit();
        }
        catch 
        {
            if (_transaction != null && _transaction.IsActive)
                _transaction.Rollback();

            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            Session.Dispose();
        }
    }

    public void Rollback()
    {
        try
        {
            if (_transaction != null && _transaction.IsActive)
                _transaction.Rollback();
        }
        finally
        {
            Session.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

WebApi Action filter:

```
public class UnitOfWorkActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public IUnitOfWork UnitOfWork { get; set; }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        UnitOfWork = actionContext.Request.GetDependencyScope().GetService(typeof(IUnitOfWork)) as IUnitOfWork;
        UnitOfWork.BeginTransaction();
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
    {
        UnitOfWork = actionExecutedContext.Request.GetDependencyScope().GetService(typeof(IUnitOfWork)) as IUnitOfWork;
        if (actionExecutedContext.Exception == null)
        {
            // commit if no exceptions
            UnitOfWork.Commit();
        }
        else
        {
            // rollback if exception
            UnitOfWork.Rollback();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: where are you getting the exception ? is it on `UnitOfWork.Commit();`

Comment: at the line _transaction = Session.BeginTransaction();

Comment: when i make a request to webapi for the first time it works, but the second time when i make a request, its not invoking the constructor. I guess it is something to do here?

Comment: Then probably it has to do with how Unity controls the lifetime of the objects. See if you scope the lifetime of UnitOfWork to a HttpRequest.

Comment: Use `PerRequestLifetimeManager` instead of `ContainerControlledLifetimeManager` and see. `ContainerControlledLifetimeManager` registers an existing object as a singleton instance which is not what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `PerRequestLifetimeManager` instead of `ContainerControlledLifetimeManager` and see. ContainerControlledLifetimeManager registers an existing object as a singleton instance which is not what you want.

see this for more info [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660872(v=pandp.20).aspx)

Comment: when i try to use this container.RegisterType<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager());  i am getting type or namespace not found for PerRequestLifetimeManager

Comment: Is that TransientLifeTimeManager?

Comment: When i used TransientLifeTimeManager, it worked. Thanks

Comment: see this link .https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.unity.perrequestlifetimemanager(v=pandp.30).aspx . Not sure why you are getting a namespace not found.